# Restful Service Development - Hosting Option

Tags: .net, asp.net, openrasta

We' re creating an API with Openrasta. What is the most effective way to host this service without IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: Please vote for the answers you find useful. You voting history is discouraging.

Answer (score 1):

Check the mailing list and documentation for the HttpListenerHost that lets you host your services out of IIS.

You can even run IIS in-process using IISCore, which is also available as a hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

Without IIS can mean two different things:

1. Still host a web service, but with some different server
2. Host the service in a process or another desktop application

Depending on the situation the answer to your question is different. Since you mention OpenRasta, I'm assuming you want option 1. If this is the case there's not much you can do without IIS, and even if you can do something, it's always going to be more difficult, just because there aren't a lot of solutions written in .NET and hosted on a non-.NET server. You won't be able to find much help, blogs and documentation. One way would be to use an [Apache server with mod_aspdotnet](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx), but I wouldn't recommend using anything else than IIS.

For option 2, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).